# Fix Extra Line Numbering in rDiscount Parser on using Octopress

Tags: markdown, octopress, rdiscount

I am trying to figure out how do I disable `rdiscount` parser to add an extra line to me `codeblocks` using octopress as a platform and Jekyll as the static site generator. I have attached the code in the image below and the left pane shows an extra line that was added (line number 5)

Source code:

```
{% codeblock lang:liquid %}
{% raw %}
{% blockquote [author [, source ]] [link] [source link title] %} {% endblockquote %}
{% blockquote Shritam Bhowmick, His Portfolio %}
To the mind that is still, the whole world surrenders.
{% endblockquote %}
{% endraw %} {% endcodeblock %}
```

Resulted Image:

[image]

Is there any markdown/liquid syntax that I had missed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the line at the end of the raw block? Like this:

```
{% codeblock lang:liquid %}
{% raw %}
{% blockquote [author [, source ]] [link] [source link title] %} {% endblockquote %}
{% blockquote Shritam Bhowmick, His Portfolio %}
To the mind that is still, the whole world surrenders.
{% endblockquote %}{% endraw %}{% endcodeblock %}
```

Comment: yes, If you look at the image, I have had erased the line. The linefeed is only to start a new heading after the blockquote.